# Исключить из коллекции элементы input type="hidden"

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

На сайте есть 6 видимых и 2 невидимых поля. Мне необходимо добавить в коллекцию только видимые.

```
<div>
    <input name="element">
    <input name "element">
    <input name="element">
    <input name "element">
    <input name="element">
    <input name "element">
    <input type="hidden" name="element">
    <input type="hidden" name "element">
</div>
```

Элементы ищу так:

```
driver.FindElements(By.Name("element"));
```

Этим способом я получаю все 8 полей, как исключить два последних? Метод должен быть универсальным, потому что количество таких полей на страницах разное.

Comment: `driver.FindElements(By.Name("element").filter(visible))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал вам для поиска элементов пользоваться XPath локаторами.

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//input[not(@type='hidden')]"));
```

То, как ими пользоваться, можно почитать, например, [здесь](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

Comment: и что делает ваш код?

Comment: @defaultlocale упс, сейчас поправлю